# Calling a column in relation to it's MAX attribute

Tags: sql, postgresql

I've tried sorting through here and asking for help but so far I've got nothing..

```
$query = "
  SELECT 
    country.name,
    MAX(city.population) as max
  FROM 
    lab6.city,
    lab6.country
  WHERE city.country_code = country.country_code
  GROUP BY country.name
  ORDER BY max DESC";
```

This returns the max population of the most populated city in a country. What I need to do is return that city from the same table that the MAX city.population was found. So far I'm pretty sure I have to use a subquery but I've been playing with this thing for hours and can't solve it.

Comment: What RDBMS are you using? Given the PHP code, I'm betting on MySQL?

Comment: What is the structure of the `city,country` tables? (what columns do they include)

Comment: PSQL, city has a population field and a name field that I need, country has a name field and is linked to city though a countrycode field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it:

```
select *
from (
  SELECT country.name as country_name,
         city.population as city_population,
         city.name  as city_name,
         rank() over (partition by country.name order by city.population desc ) as population_rank
  FROM lab6.city
    JOIN lab6.country ON city.country_code = country.country_code
) t
where population_rank = 1;
```

Due to the use of a window function you can select any additional column you want as you are no long limited by the `group by` restrictions.

More information on window functions can be found in the manual: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tutorial-window.html

Comment: This is awesome! How do I keep it from displaying the rank though?

Comment: @user3396915: don't use `select *` in the outer query (I was too lazy to list all columns explicitly there)

Comment: That just taught me a ton. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

This will return multiple cities per country if the max population is shared. The join with Country in the query to get the max is actually not needed. You only need it if you want to know the country name also.

```
SELECT co.name, c.city, c.population FROM lab6.city c
INNER JOIN lab6.country co ON co.country_code = c.country_code
INNER JOIN
(SELECT country_code, MAX(population) as max
FROM   lab6.city
GROUP BY country_code) max
ON c.population = max.max
AND c.country_code = max.country_code;
```

Comment: Query failed: ERROR: column reference "country_code" is ambiguous LINE 8: AND country_code = max.country_code; ^

Comment: Works great! Now I just need to get the corresponding country and the population of the cities listen to display as well. Everytime I try to touch display country it screws up and only displays one country name over and over.

Comment: To get country name you need that join to country, and population can simply be extracted from the city table. I've edited that in.

Comment: $query = "SELECT co.name, city.name, max.max FROM lab6.city INNER JOIN lab6.country as co ON city.country_code = co.country_code INNER JOIN(SELECT country_code, MAX(population) as max FROM lab6.city GROUP BY country_code) max ON city.population = max.max AND city.country_code = max.country_code";

Returns everything except for the country.

Comment: What's the value of the first column then, if it's not the country name?